# Gaussian Elimination in Python with Pivoting

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian, numerical-analysis

Having trouble with this problem. I can't tell what's wrong. It seems a bit too complicated and I'm getting errors. I actually did this with pseudocode from wikipedia.

```
import numpy as np
import math

A = [[5,1,0,2,1],[0,4,0,1,2],[1,1,4,1,1],[0,1,2,6,0],[0,0,1,2,4]]
b = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]

def swap_rows(A,i,j):
    temp = A[i]
    A[i]=A[j]
    A[j] = temp
    return(A) 

def Gauss(A):
    n = len(A)
    for k in range(n):
        myList = []
        for p in range(k,n):
            myList.append(abs(A[p][k]))
        i_max = np.argmax(myList)
        if A[i_max][k] == 0:
            print('Error: Matrix is singular')
            return
        A = swap_rows(a,k,i_max)
        for i in range(k,n):
            f = (A[i][k])/(A[k][k])
            for j in range(k,n):
                A[i][j] = A[i][j]-A[k][j]*f
        A[i][k] = 0
    return(A)

Gauss(A)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). .. [mcve]

Comment: As an aside, python has a swap idiom that doesn't require a temporary variable, so just `A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]`